# defining a mongoengine model with ListField that cannot be empty

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, wtforms

I am using flask-mongoengine and my model `Post` has fields `title`, `slug`, `body` and `tags`. Each `Post` has a unique `slug` and each `Post` needs to have at least 1 tag. So `tags` is a `list` of `strings` with at least 1 element.

```
class Post(db.Document):
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    slug = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True, unique=True)
    body = db.StringField(required=True)
    tags = db.ListField(db.StringField(max_length=255), required=True)   #each post should have at least one tag

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return url_for('post', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    meta = {
        'allow_inheritance': False,
        'indexes': ['-created_at', 'slug', 'title', 'tags'],
        'ordering': ['-created_at'],
        'collection': 'posts',
    }
```

when i create a form in the template for entering a new post, each tag is entered in a new text box with name `tags` so if i have 3 tags for a `Post` then there would be 3 text boxes with each having name `tags`
Here is how the view is

```
from flask.ext.mongoengine.wtf import model_form
class CreateEdit(MethodView):

    form = model_form(Post)    #Gets object of class PostForm which is a subclass of ModelForm, ModelForm is a subclass of Form
    def post(self, slug = None):
        form = self.form(request.form)   #Populate PostForm with data from the request
        post = Post()
        form.populate_obj(post)
        post.save()
        flash('Update successful')
```

Now i get a `mongoengine.base.ValidationError` error in the browser. 
The data that i pass in the post request (Courtesy: Firebug)

```
title: third post
slug: 3rd
body: this is the 3rd post
tags: third
tags: last
```

When i inspected in the debugger `request.form` shows

```
werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict({'body': u'this is the 3rd post    \r\n  ', 'title': u'third post', 'slug': u'3rd', 'tags': u'third'})
```

now there are multiple `tags` in the form but only one is present in the dictionary. This is OK because its a dictionary so there cant be multiple keys with same name. But when i inspect `form.data` it shows

```
{'body': u'this is the 3rd post    \r\n  ', 'title': u'third post', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 24, 14, 7, 18, 97273), 'tags': [], 'slug': u'3rd'  }
```

the `tags` field is an empty list which is absurd because it should be populated with `tags` from `request.form`. Also if i enter `print request.form` in the debugger i get

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('body', u'this is the 3rd post    \r\n  '), ('title', u'third post'), ('slug', u'3rd'), ('tags', u'third'), ('tags', u'last')])
```

So it means the `request` object retains multiple values for the same name to show it in the representation(`__repr__`) but passes only one value to the `ModelForm` object. But my `ModelForm` is not getting any value for `tags`.

Whats wrong?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I haven't used WTForms before. Is a [FieldList](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList) different to a `ListField`?

Comment: @AlexL No. They are same. See [here](https://flask-mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). In the `Supported fields` section

Answer (score 0):

Your Code works for me

Werkzeug uses a MultiDict that can contain multiple keys with the same name http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/

When I try 3 input fields with the same name and inspect request.form in the debugger i get: `ImmutableMultiDict([('tag', u'1'), ('tag', u'2'), ('tag', u'3')])`

and can get the values with `request.form.getlist('tag')`

Could it be due to an old version of flask/werkzeug?

Comment: I am using Flask `0.9` and Werkezeug `0.8.3`. Which version are you running?